# How can you target a previous $(this)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that is fired when a user clicks on a link. When they click on another link, I want to alter the first link that they clicked on. How would I go about doing this? This is what I have so far:

```
$('a').click(function(){
  //some code ...
  if ( $(this).attr('id') != last.attr('id') ) {
    $('a').click(function()
      /*the original $this*/.parent().parent().quickFlipper({refresh: 0});
      /*the original last*/.parent().parent().quickFlipper({refresh: 0});
    });
    var that = this;
    var that2 = last;
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(that).parent().parent().quickFlipper({refresh :0});
      $(that2).parent().parent().quickFlipper({refresh :0});
    }, 1500);
  //some more code ...
});
```

Thanks in advance and please ask any questions if you are unsure of what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good time to use a closure.

```
$('a').click((function () {

   //private
   var lastClicked;

   return function () {
      //your code

      if(lastClicked) {
         //do something to the last clicked element
      }

      lastClicked = this;
   };
})());
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/Mus6N/

Comment: +1 Very interesting. Fixed a small JS error found when fiddling.

Comment: Where is `lastClicked` actually stored?

Comment: It's stored within the first function.  Since functions retain scope (in JavaScript), the inner function (the event handler) has access to `lastClicked` and no other function can tamper with that variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
var previousElement;

$('a').click(function(){
  //some code ...
  previouseElement = ($this);
  if ( $(this).attr('id') != last.attr('id') ) {
    $('a').click(function()
      $(this).parent().parent().quickFlipper({refresh: 0});
      previousElement.parent().parent().quickFlipper({refresh: 0});
    });
    var that = this;
    var that2 = last;
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(that).parent().parent().quickFlipper({refresh :0});
      $(that2).parent().parent().quickFlipper({refresh :0});
    }, 1500);
  //some more code ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastClicked = null;

$('a').click(function(){
  //some code ...
  if (lastClicked && $(this).attr('id') != lastClicked.attr('id') ) {
       $(this).parent().parent().quickFlipper({refresh: 0});
      lastClicked.parent().parent().quickFlipper({refresh: 0});

    lastClicked = $(this);
  }
});
```

like that?

Answer (score 0):

Use a global var for last.

something like

```
$(function(){
    var lastClick;
    $('a').click(function(){
        //do stuff to last click here
        lastClick = $(this); //make this at the bottom
    });
});
```